# I need help with my mead. Did i go wrong?

Tags: mead

So i just started making my homemade mead for first time and i had been fermenting it for 3 weeks. But it has stopped bubbling and i was worried it stopped carbonating and it smells like strong wine and tastes of it too. Did i do something wrong or is it the brand of yeast?.

Comment: Maybe it is done fermenting? If so, enjoy! What is the specific gravity reading? What is the pH level? What is the temperature?

Answer (score 2):

If it smells and tastes like wine, then congratulations, you've made mead.  Whether it's a mead that you enjoy, or not, is a matter of experience and personal preference.

Comment: I thought it takes month to make mead not a couple of weeks

Comment: @MarkSimpson Maybe you had perfect conditions. Cannot know if there is more alcohol potential without more data.

Comment: It depends primarily on fermentation temperature.  What temp did you ferment at?

Answer (score 1):

sample the mead and check the gravity and flavor. it should be within 0.05 of 1.000 and not terribly sweet if done

Comment: This should be a comment.  Please make sure to answer the question "Did i do something wrong or is it the brand of yeast?"